# SQL group by result

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a SQL statement that gives me the following result:

[image]

What I am now trying is to group all results to one row. The rule is: If there is any "Ja" found in one of the results the field "GG" should say "Ja".

What do I need to do?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: show a sample of expected o/p.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you want the query to group according to the column gg
So...

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY gg
```